# How can you return the most recent posts from custom post types in random order

Tags: php, wordpress

How can you return the most recent posts from custom post types  in random order

my code is below:

```
$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'cme-education', 'post', 'media_gallery', 'learning-zone' ),
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'post__not_in' => $clicked_activities_array,
    //'post__in' => $args1,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'post_date' => 'DESC',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'vocabulary_1',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => array(2, 21)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Random query is heavy. Just get 10 latest posts, orderby date descending. Then on frontend add them random css order:x styles and make them in a flex container. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: they need to pull in random order on page refresh. Flex order would not achieve this

Comment: you can mix flex order with javascript. Or else if you need php way - you can reorder array of objects before outputting. But you wont be able to cache results. With js you can cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using the `date_query` argument which accepts a date filter and allowed me to use the `orderby => 'rand` to get random posts. Anyway for those who may come across a similar issue the code I used is below.

```
$before_date = date('d F Y', strtotime("+2 days"));
$after_date = date('d F Y', strtotime("-1 years"));

$recently_added_activities = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'cme-education', 'post', 'media_gallery', 'learning-zone' ),
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'post__not_in' => $clicked_activities_array,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => $after_date,
            'before'     => $before_date,
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'vocabulary_1',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => $postTerm
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: 'orderby'=>'rand' is very slow database request, that will get progressively slower the more posts you have in database. As I mentioned in comment to your question, its better to avoid using it, and instead code pseudo-random solution with php https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php or javascript + css flex order.

quote from google: https://i.gyazo.com/2c085550407724c7dc98271b1608bffb.png